# How to properly use operator.itemgetter to do double sort

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I am trying to use itemgetter to do a double sort in python, but I can't seem to grasp it. What I want to do is first sort by 'var2' and then by 'var4', but keeping it sorted by 'var2'. I have the following piece of code that should help (I adapted it from another SO question):

```
df = df[['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4']]
df = sorted(df, key=operator.itemgetter(1,2))
```

but I am not sure what the arguments mean for itemgetter. I tried running it the way it is, but all I get are the variables' names.

I also tried doing

```
df = sorted(df, key=operator.itemgetter(2,4))
```

but I get the following error: 'IndexError: string index out of range'.

Please help.

**Edit: example**

I have four variables: date, time, price and a number. I want to sort the dataframe by date, but within each date I want to sort it by the number. I hope this makes sense.

```
date            time        price   number

09/02/2008  00:20:38    46.0    9987

09/03/2009  07:00:49    46.65   8551

07/05/2008  07:00:51    46.75   13681

08/02/2008  07:00:57    46.75   14022

09/02/2008  07:01:00    46.75   10270

09/08/2008  07:01:11    46.75   14850

09/02/2008  07:01:22    46.75   20568

08/02/2008  07:01:24    46.75   15683

09/02/2008  07:02:16    46.65   11698
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`operator.itemgetter(a, b, c)` is equivalent to `lambda x: x[a][b][c]`, not to `lambda x: (x[a], x[b], x[c])`.

What you really want is:

```
sorted(df, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[3]))
```

Also note that I changed the indices 2 and 4 to 1 and 3; Python indexes start with 0.

---

Since you appear to be using `pandas` DataFrames, not lists (next time, mention that in your question), here's how you sort a DataFrame by value:

```
df.sort_values(['time', 'number'])
```

Call `df.sort_values` with a column or a list of columns to sort by. Don't assign this to anything; `df.sort_values` works in-place.

Comment: Somehow it says that the name 'x' is not defined. I thought that here 'x' could be just anything. Do I have to define it first?

Comment: @LauraSimonsenLeal Oh, sorry, I made a mistake; I fixed it in my edit.

Comment: The error went back to 'IndexError: string index out of range'. =/

Comment: @LauraSimonsenLeal please put a full reproducible example in your question - on my end this works.

Comment: @LauraSimonsenLeal I edited my answer regarding sorting `pandas` data frames.

Comment: It worked mind-blowingly well!! I wish I can be as awesome as you in this someday. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @LauraSimonsenLeal No problem. All I did was google it and read the documentation, but I guess that takes practice, too. :)